# How to do Three column Addition?

Tags: tables, math-mode, xlop

I want to write a primary school sheet of exercices (additions in columns) with big digits in LaTeX. When i want to do two columns, it is easy with `xlop`, but i can't to do three columns!

How to do Three column Additions?
Like this:

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [amsi.org.au](http://www.amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/B6/B6t7.png))</sub>

**I only need format it**, it isn't necessary to solved it.

Comment: Do you need LaTeX to calculate the answer, or merely format it?

Comment: I only need format it. I edit the question... thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{blue!25}% specifies the \hline colour using xcolor

\[ \begin{array}{*4r}
     &{}^11&{}^16&3\\
     &5    &4    &9\\
     &2    &7    &6\\ \hline
    +&9    &8    &8\\ \hline
   \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

The colours are slightly gratuitous:)

**EDIT** Actually, I don't like this as the columns have different widths. Using the [array](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) we can fix this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hfill$}p{1em}<{$\hfill}}
\arrayrulecolor{blue!25}
\[ \begin{array}{cCCC}
     &{}^11&{}^16&3\\
     &5    &4    &9\\
     &2    &7    &6\\ \hline
    +&9    &8    &8\\ \hline
   \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

Now we have:

[image]

It's a bit of a hack. Hopefully some one else will contribute a more elegant solution.